# Getting string in between delimiters

Tags: c++, string, delimiter

Good day everyone,

I have problems with breaking down string ("cutting" and using part of string which is in between delimiters).

So far this is was what I managed to do:

```
    std::string begin_processed_received_DATA = "&7?@670*/5#^";
    std::string end_processed_received_DATA = "*8d4a#%";

    processed_received_DATA = receive_DATA;

    //Checks if delimiter exists in message (by setting NO_DELIMITER to represent number where END DELMITER is in string array)
    std::size_t NO_DELIMITER = processed_received_DATA.find(end_processed_received_DATA);

    if (NO_DELIMITER != std::string::npos) {
        //Deletes string from end
        processed_received_DATA.resize(processed_received_DATA.find(end_processed_received_DATA));

        //Deletes string from begining (starting at string[0])
        processed_received_DATA.erase(0, processed_received_DATA.find(begin_processed_received_DATA) + begin_processed_received_DATA.size());
    }

    else {
        return 201502;
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I should approach this problem ?

Example `receive_DATA` would be somthing like this: `984GE#$% 534'694 4685)_(9357uf0 di,stre89/4&7?@670*/5#^nulter.dd/se 895/68.476*8d4a#%897 R#3t746+- @1`

I must notify that my `receive_DATA` string consists many symbols, numbers, whitespaces, letters and is approximately 20000 symbols long.
Here is the [picture](http://s29.postimg.org/5eh5emq93/String.png) to get an idea what kind of string it is.
(I remember solving such problem with way shorter string in similar manner)

Comment: So you want to get the contents between `"&7?@670*/5#^"` and `"*8d4a#%"`?

Comment: Depending on your delimiters, using resize, erase etc can be costly memory moves. You could use a pointer, find your delimiter, copy your string character by character to a new string until you hit the next delimiter..

Comment: Also what is the actual problem?  Does this not work?  If so how does it not work?

Comment: Yes, I want to get contents between `"&7?@670*/5#^"` and `"*8d4a#%"`
And the problem is that program stops working with my solution (as it is with Pete's Becker's solution too). And if you ask about debuging info, I don't have any of it, this supposed to be quickly written program to solve one simple problem, no IDE, quick compile.

Comment: @BugFinder
That what I was thinking. I thought I will see one of possible solutions provided with character by character scanning in a proper/efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find()` method of the standard `string` class. As you can read more about [here,](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) this method returns the first index of a substring within a string.

I'm assuming that `receive_DATA` is a `std::string` as it is not explicitly declared in your code sample.

What you want to do is start by finding the positions of your delimiters like this:

```
size_t dataBegin = receive_DATA.find(begin_proccessed_received_DATA) + 
                                    begin_proccessed_received_DATA.length();
string dataAfterFirstDelim;

size_t dataEnd;
if (dataBegin != string::npos)
{
    dataAfterFirstDelim = receive_DATA.substr(dataBegin, 
                                                     receive_DATA.length() - dataBegin);
    dataEnd = dataAfterFirstDelim.find(end_proccessed_received_DATA);

}
```

Note that you have to add the length of the first delimiter to the beginning position of that delimiter to find the beginning of your data. From there you only need to search after the beginning of your data (as pointed out by @SergeBallesta) for the second delimiter.

When you know where these occur in your string you can easily find the substring between them using the [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method which takes a starting position and a length. Since you have a string now that starts with your data you can do the substring from the start of it to the ending point of your data.

```
if (dataBegin != string::npos && dataEnd != string::npos)
{
    processed_received_DATA = dataAfterFirstDelim.substr(0, dataEnd);
}
```

Comment: Ok for the search for `dataBegin` (even if it should be a `size_t` and not an int), but you should only search the end from there: `int dataEnd = receive_DATA.find(end_proccessed_received_DATA, dataBegin);`

Comment: So far, no luck with your solution. It does cut ending, leaving one space after it, but everything what is in the begining (majority of the data) stays unchanged.

Comment: [This link](http://cpp.sh/65kx) is a working example of my code. I used your sample data. Check what you've written against this.

Comment: Everything is perfectly fine, I think it may be related with `receive_DATA` size and non unicode symbols maybe

Comment: The size shouldn't be an issue. You said that your input could be about 20000 characters long. The [maximum size](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/max_size/) of a string object in c++ is 4294967291.

Comment: I knew that, just the more time I spend coding, the more I want to doubt everything :D
Here is the [picture](http://s29.postimg.org/5eh5emq93/String.png), it may help to get better idea what kind of string it is.

Comment: I'm not seeing your beginning delimiter in that string. I see `7?@670*/5#^` down at the bottom, but that is one character off of your delimiter.

Comment: It is there, I just painted it by an accident.

Comment: In that case I would recommend stepping through with a debugger to see exactly what is not going as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string find_delimited(const std::string& data,
        const std::string& begin_delimiter,
        const std::string& end_delimiter) {
    std::size_t begin = data.find(begin_delimiter);
    if (begin == std::string::npos)
        // error: begin_delimiter not found
    begin += begin_delimiter.size();
    std::size_t end = data.find(end_delimiter, start;
    if (end == std::string::npos) 
        // error: end_delimiter not found
    return data.substr(begin, end - begin);
}
```